# Arduino Mega | bulding a left right sensor

Tags: arduino, distance, sensors

I'm working on an air hockey table project where a human player is playing against and automatic machine player.
I need a way for the machine player to know if the object advancing towords machine player is on the left side of the automatic player or the right side.

I need a way to get this information lots of times, a few times per second so the automatic player will know which side the needs to move to, in order to hit the object.

Any ideas on which sensors I can use and how in order to do so?

Comment: I am not 100% sure if I should put this as an answer. Thats why as a comment. Maybe this [ultra-sonic](http://www.trossenrobotics.com/p/ultra-sonic-range-measurement-module.aspx) sensor is helping you. If not you can also visit this [site](http://www.trossenrobotics.com/c/arduino-range-sensors-distance-object.aspx) to find a more applicable sensor for your needs.

Comment: So much possibilities... Money? I think something like a laser-harp. You could make something like a laser array/matrix...

Comment: I don't think that the ultrasonic module fits this prject. The target is small and fast... Now, I don't know what the speed is, but I think thatyou can solve this in two ways: 1) put a magnet under the object and a grid of coils under the table. 2) with a camera and some image processing. I don't think that the object speed is greater than 5m/s, so a 100fps camera (even the raspicam can arrive at 90fps - and it costs around 50$) can detect it within 5 cm (so you can track it quite easily, I think)

Comment: Camera is an option and could work thank to big difference between the black of the puck and the white of table. If you only need the side where the puck is, it could work fine